# Coding brain teaser to update an array (language agnostic)

Tags: algorithm, puzzle, code-golf

All,

I need a clever way to implement this algorithm (for work) as quickly and cleanly as possible:
I think I've removed all the language specific issues and boiled it down to this:

I have two arrays: A and B.

A has a list of names in it {Apple, Apple, Banana, Banana, Banana, Carrot, ...} each i-th value has no upper limit on the number of times it can appear in A. There can be just one "Apple" or a zillion.

Each entry in A has a matching entry in B. (many to many mapping). For example:

```c
A[0] = "Apple"      B[0] = "0027"
A[1] = "Apple"      B[1] = "0028"
A[2] = "Banana"     B[2] = "0073"
A[3] = "Banana"     B[3] = "0041"
A[4] = "Banana"     B[4] = "0069"
```

If there are 100 or fewer instances of an entry in A, (if there are <= 100 Bananas) then they must all share the same initial "B" value. If there are more than 100, then the first 100 must share the same B values, but the next 100 will have the B[i + 100] th value.

Example if there are 102 apples

```c
A[0]   = "Apple"       B[0]   = "0027"
A[1]   = "Apple"       B[1]   = "0028"
...
A[99]  = "Apple"       B[99]  = "0073"
A[100] = "Apple"       B[100] = "0041"
A[101] = "Apple"       B[101] = "0069"
A[102] = "Banana"      B[102] = "0123"
```

Then the result that I want is this:

```c
A[0]   = "Apple"       B[0]   = "0027"
A[1]   = "Apple"       B[1]   = "0027"
...
A[99]  = "Apple"       B[99]  = "0027"
A[100] = "Apple"       B[100] = "0041"
A[101] = "Apple"       B[101] = "0041"
A[102] = "Banana"      B[102] = "0123"
```

I'm sure there are some super brains out there that can come up with the crappy algorithm I've devised, so let's see it!

**Edit 1:** Guess I should point out that this *was* for work. I thought this was a fun challenge that someone might want to look at and possibly come up with a better solution than the one I came up with.

**Edit 2:** Thanks to daniel for pointing out my dumb mistakes.

### My solution just for comparison (pseudo code):

first make a hash/dictionary of B, called d where d[ "Apple" ] = number of instances of Apple in A.

```c
while (i < A.count)
{
    string cmp = A[i];
    int v = d[cmp];
    int j=i;

    while (v--) {
       B[j++] = B[i];

       if (j %100 == 0)
       i += j
    }
    i+= d[cmp];
}
```

doing this from memory, hope I didn't screw up an indexes...

Comment: So, you need this for work and tag it as “fun”, “puzzle”, and “challenge”? And you probably are not willing to pay anything for it? Did I understand that right?

Comment: dude, I've already solved it. I just thought others might have something better. And some people actually do like these types of puzzles/challenges -- at least I do.

Comment: Is your **A** array always sorted, as you showed in examples? If so - there is no any challenge... :(

Comment: Apple => i = 0 => B[i + 101] = B[101] = "0069", not "0041". Am I wrong or are you?

Comment: Or does it mean, that the items 0...99 get the value of item 0 and the remaining items 100...* the value of item 100?

Comment: mikhail, yes It's always sorted. And yes I know it's probably easy for the geniuses out there, I just want to see how a genius would solve this since I'm not one of them.

Daniel -- I was wrong. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Is the B array free from duplicates, or could it be the case that each of 200 "Apple"s is mapped to "0027" in the input?

Comment: What about the item 201? Still the value from item 101 or now from item 201?

Comment: B has no duplicates. And every 100 values should have a new "B" value. That is A[0..99] has B[0], A[100..199] => B[100], A[200..299] = B[200]

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion in C# as far as I unterstood the question and assuming the arrays are sorted.

```
String[] A = GetAs();
String[] B = GetBs();

Int32 count = 0;
Int32 index = 1;

while (index < A.Length)
{
   if (A[index] != A[index - 1])
   {
      count = 0;
   }

   currentCount++;

   if ((A[index] == A[index - 1]) && (count % 100 != 1))
   {
      B[index] = B[index - 1];
   }

   index++;
}
```

If one likes it compact (and a zero based count).

```
String[] A = GetAs();
String[] B = GetBs();

Int32 c = 0, i = 1;

while (i < A.Length)
{
   c = (A[i] == A[i - 1]) ? c + 1 : 0;

   B[i] = ((A[i] == A[i - 1]) && (c % 100 != 0)) ? B[i - 1] : B[i];

   i++;
}
```

Comment: I think currentCount %100 == 1 rather than currentCount == 101. What should happen if you have 202 Apples in a row?

Comment: Corrected the behavior to modulo 100.

Comment: `c = (A[i] == A[i - 1]) ? c + 1 : 0;` could be `c = (A[i] == A[i - 1]) * (c + 1);` - saves a branch

Answer (score 0):

I'd want to build up a dictionary/hashtable, something like

```
{'Apple':
    {'NumberSeen':102,
     'BValues':['0027','0041']
    },
 'Banana':
    {'NumberSeen':1,
     'BValues':['0123']
    }
}
```

Then you loop over this, adding a new b value if NumberSeen%100 = 1, then recreate the B-array from this dictionary.

EDIT: This gets you a readable solution which handles an unsorted list. I just saw your 'list is sorted' comment, which means you can do it a lot simpler, in O(1) space, but I'm not sure how clear the code would be.

Answer (score 0):

```
String curFruit = A[0];
int curFruitCount = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i].equals(curFruit) && curFruitCount < 100) {
        B[i] = B[i-1];
        curFruitCount++;
    }else{
        curFruit = A[i];
        curFruitCount = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like Daniel Brückner's solution but I think you might be able to make one enhancement on it.  Assuming the 'A's are sorted and spurts of 100 consecutive identical fruits are common, then you could take advantage of that by adding the following check:

```
String[] A = GetAs();
String[] B = GetBs();
Int32 c = 0, i = 1;
while (i < A.Length)
{   
    if(i+99 < A.Length && A[i] == A[i+99])
    {
        for(int j=1;j<100;j++) b[i+j] = b[i];

        i = i+99;
    }
    else
    {
        B[i] = (A[i] == A[i - 1]) ? B[i - 1] : B[i];   
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only any array shorter than 101 items will make it crash.

Comment: I knew I should have proof read it again.  I added a check for that.
Thanks Dykam.